# Mobile Broad Band connection Problem

Tags: networking, modem

I recently Bought Huawei E303F Data card It is working nice in windows 8.1 but in ubuntu connection cant be established using it

Modem is recognised but when i tried to connect it is is failing to do so

Any solution for the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem: `lsusb` was detecting the card properly, and so was NetworkManager but it was unable to connect.

The solution that finally worked for me was to use `wvdial`. Running `wvdialconf` in the terminal with my modem plugged in automatically detected it and generated the config file (`/etc/wvdial.conf`) which I then edited. But you can also directly create the file without running that command.

Here's how my `/etc/wvdial.conf` file looks, after editing:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 460800

[Dialer vodafone]
Username = vodafone
Password = vodafone
Phone = *99#
```

*To edit `/etc/wvdial.conf`, you need to have root permissions. Typing `sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf` in the terminal will open the required file*

Now, running `wvdial vodafone` should get you connected to the net.

You may need to change `ttyUSB0` with some other modem, depending on which port your modem is set to.

Another problem I've heard some people encounter is that the usb sticks has several modes: one for the "CD" with drivers, one for the optional microSD card, and one for the modem itself. So it may get detected as a wrong device, making the connection fail (eg. trying to connect to the Internet through the microSD reader). There are other forums, like [this one](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1734),  which describes how to do this using `usb_modeswitch`. **TODO: If anybody *has* done this, please update this post to give proper instructions**

Answer (score 0):

Open Network Connections, and edit the connection which you are trying to use. Under the PPP settings tab, click on the configure methods button, try disabling some methods and try to connect again. I have only PAP and MSCHAP v2 enabled and it is works fine for me.

[image]